# dnsmasq doesn’t resolve domains while internet connection is disabled

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, dnsmasq

On mac OS (El Capitan) I have a virtual machine `vagrant` with `laravel-homestead` box. In one of my dev projects I need to use dynamically created subdomains for each user registered on site (e.g. user.sitename.dev, user2.sitename.dev, etc.). So, I used `dnsmasq` to do this and everything works fine but only with internet connection. If I disable connection, dnsmasq doesn’t resolve domains. Here are my configuration files:

***Local:***

```
/etc/resolver/dev:
  nameserver 192.168.10.10

/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf:
  address=/.dev/192.168.10.10
```

***Virtual machine:***

```
/etc/dnsmasq.conf:
  local=/dev/
  domain=dev
  address=/.dev/192.168.10.10

/etc/nginx/sites-available/sitename:
  server_name sitename.dev *.sitename.dev;
```

What can be the reason of this problem?